# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent while reading files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I'm getting below error while trying to read file and sending the response back to browser.

```
[ 'Error: Can\'t set headers after they are sent.',
  '    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)',
  '    at ServerResponse.setWriteHeadHeaders (/somepath/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:82:19)',
  '    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/somepath/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:41:36)',
  '    at /somepath/server/custom.js:71:13',
  '    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)' ]
```

```html
var fs = require('fs');

exports.customPageChatStatus = function(req, res) {
 if(req.params._pagename === 'Test123')
 {
      fs.readFile("/somepath/Test123.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
        res.end(data);
      });
 }
 if(req.params._pagename === 'SecondFile')
 {
      fs.readFile("/somepath/SecondFile.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
        res.end(data);
      });
 }
 else {
  fs.readFile("/somepath/InActive.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
        res.end(data);
      });
 }
};
```

Interestingly I'm seeing the above error only when reading 1st file (Test123.txt) and no issue when reading "SecondFile.txt".

Appreciate any help on resolving this!

Comment: this error is ocuured when you already run res.end() and call it again

Comment: I've used conditions to execute the block only once and only if it matches the pagename received in request. I'm not sure if it has run twice or multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here if you use else if in your statements that will resolve your issue

```
var fs = require('fs');

    exports.customPageChatStatus = function(req, res) {
        if(req.params._pagename === 'Test123')
        {
                fs.readFile("/somepath/Test123.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
              if (err) console.log(err);
               res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
            res.end(data);
                });
        }
        else if(req.params._pagename === 'SecondFile')
        {
                fs.readFile("/somepath/SecondFile.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
               if (err) console.log(err);
               res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
            res.end(data);
                });
        }
        else {
            fs.readFile("/somepath/InActive.txt", 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
               res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
            res.end(data);
                });
        }
    };
```

Comment: if i help you than please accept answer and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing that the if..else if.. is actually a problem. Am sure both the conditions can never be true.

I thought of a more succinct approach.

A simpler code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.customPageChatStatus = function(req, res) {
    let pagename = req.params.pagename;

    if (pagename !== 'Test123' || pagename !== 'Secondfile') pagename = 'InActive';

    fs.readFile(`/somepath/${pagename}.txt`, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
    return res.end(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Please notice the use of 'return'